# Проблема с работой скрипта http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты

Пользователи нашего сайта жалуются, что у них не отображаются карты. Проблема воспроизводиться периодически, и у разных провайдеров.
Не подскажете, какую версию лучше использовать вместо http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ушёл на google map и проблем не знаю. Ушёл именно из-за различных багов яндекс карт. Типа вашей и ещё кучи багов.

Comment: Вам стоит обратиться в техподдержку API Карт. Это актуальная версия и такая ошибка не возникает просто так - она может быть связана, например, с автоматической блокировкой вашего сайта за превышение лимитов.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема из-за того, что теперь АПИ http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU отдает файл а не json